# Watch entries disappear when using CreateObject for Excel.Application

Tags: vba, office365, office-automation

I have some VBA code in an Access database which creates an object using CreateObject("Excel.Application"). I have added a watch on a string variable. When I try to step through the code, the watch entry for the string goes blank when I hit the line where the CreateObject occurs. The little icon for the watch that looks like a pair of eye glasses is still visible, but all of the other data for the watch is invisible. If I continue stepping through the code, the watch values reappear when the Sub P2 is entered. On return to P1, the watches disappear again. Finally, when I set the object variable to Nothing the watch values reappear. This same behavior occurs if I use Word.Application or PowerPoint.Application. Also, if I click on the watch while it is invisible, the values reappear. However, if I use something like Scripting.Dictionary when creating the object, the watch remains visible. It seems to only happen with MS Office applications. I am using Office 365 with the latest updates. I also tried turning off hardware graphic acceleration, but it didn't help. This seems like a bug in the VBA environment, but I thought someone else might have had some experience with it.

```
Sub P1()
    Dim App As Object
    Dim str As String
    
    str = "test"
    Set App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    Set App = Nothing
End Sub
Sub P2()
    Debug.Print "In P2"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the Excel object model on the COM references dialog of your VBA project. Than you may try to use [Early binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients#early-binding) instead.

See [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients#early-binding) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding the Excel reference and the watch values still disappear. I tried the same code from an Excel work book and it does the same thing.